# Apps can't reach partition but i can

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, mount, 20.04, fstab

i am dualbooting ubuntu 20 with windows 10.
I can reach it using nautilus or terminal and edit without sudo but when apps try to reach it (npm, onlyoffice, deluge, firefox) they get permission error. `whoami` gives my user not root. Fast boot not active. When i try to change permission or try to own the folders it just revert back to root. How can i make partition reachable for apps.

I have 3 partitions: Windows, ortak(shared) and linux. Ortak is the one with problems. Windows and linux aren't installed in it.

My fstab is:

```
`/dev/disk/by-uuid/D67060B97060A1CB /media/ortak auto rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,async,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

`ls -l` is

```
total 2269
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       0 Eki 11  2019 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    4096 Haz 16 15:15  Dev
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    8192 Haz 10 22:16  Download
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    4096 Haz  6 16:08  Eğitim
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  262144 Nis 17 16:52  Müzik
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      12 Haz 14 18:06  ortak -> /media/ortak
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       0 Şub  6 20:21 'System Volume Information'
```

Comment: What is Ortak??

Comment: What is exactly the error message you get when you try to access or write to that filesystem via for example firefox ? If you open firefox in terminal you can see the error messages.

Comment: Why mounted in media? Why not mnt?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha **/media/user/DISK_LABEL** is the default mount point for disk partitions in the debian-based systems.But there's no difference between that and **/mnt**.

Comment: Hmm. Isn't there a thing like /mnt is for internal drives/partitions and /media is for removable drives? I read somewhere...

Comment: Something possibly wrong with the fstab? I don't see anything though. Does the order matter. Like will putting `user` before `suid,dev,exec,` do something. Why do you need `user` anyway. Do multiple users use the PC?

Comment: @summertime Ortak is the name of the partition

Comment: @Parsa Mousavi To first message => I don't really see any messages other than permission denied. https://imgur.com/a/oE7jxT4
To second message=> I agree.

Comment: @Sasuke Uchiha To first message => No real reason. Nothing changes. Tried both ways.
To third message => No idea. It was auto generated by the disks app. I tried changing it in some ways. Nothing changed.

Comment: Hmm.  If those aren't your custom ones, you really don't need to have that many tags. Try this line. This is what I have.  `/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D60CFF0BF1D440 /media/ortak ntfs-3g users,uid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137,x-gvfs-show,utf8 0 0` Make a backup of fstab before you do this (`sudo nano -B /etc/fstab`).

Comment: Onlyoffice same. Firefox is very strange. I downloads the file to the dir but when i say open dir there is only the file downloaded. Everything else isn't there. `pwd` shows `/media/artidokuz/ortak/ortak` but i selected `media/ortak/downloads`

Comment: @artidokuz Did changing the fstab work or did you find a solution?

Comment: Sadly Nothing changed